# IOS PWA Application support Web NFC API

Tags: javascript, ios, webkit, progressive-web-apps, webnfc

I'm developing a PWA application for Android, IOS and Web Application. In android and IOS, I need to provide NFC capability, I'm using Web NFC API. From what I understand, Web NFC API developed by chromium project and based in blink browser engine. However, IOS browser is using webkit engine. From what I read from following link, IOS block Web NFC API.
https://webkit.org/tracking-prevention/

May I know any solution I can implement web nfc api in IOS?

Comment: The Web NFC API is not yet available in Safari and iOS Chrome. You need to build a native iOS application to access the NFC API.

Comment: @AndorPolgar But i'm developing PWA and not no plan to develop native IOS application. How can I access for NFC API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web NFC is not supported by iOS. Neither in Chrome or Safari.

It is supported at the time of writing only on Android in Chrome 89.
See https://web.dev/nfc/#browser-support